# Must I take baggage through customs when flying through Heathrow?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, luggage, lhr

I am flying with Heathrow on a stopover (bought a ticket from TLV(Tel Aviv) to Heathrow to YYZ (Toronto)). My first leg is on ElAl. My plane lands at a different terminal than it takes off from.

Do I have to take my bag, go through customs, etc. or does the airport take care of it?